# Is there a command in AIX similar to fallocate in Linux

Tags: filesystems, aix

I am looking for a way to occupy space in an AIX file system without doing much IO.

I have tried `dd` and `lmktemp`.  `dd` creates a sparse file, but does not
lock the space. `lmktemp` does the job well but there is some IO and 
is a bit time consuming. I believe `fallocate` is quick and no IO.

Comment: just to clarify, jfs? jfs2?

Comment: jfs2 and we do have some gpfs

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is: No, AIX does not provide that command fallocate. AIX provides the library call posix_fallocate().

For more details:

```
root@x066:[/data/prj/python/python3-3.6.8]find /usr/include -name \*.h | xargs egrep "(fallocate|truncate)64\("
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              ftruncate64(int, off64_t);
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              truncate64(const char *, off64_t);

root@x066:[/data/prj/python/python3-3.6.8]find /usr/include -name \*.h | xargs egrep "(fallocate|truncate)\("
/usr/include/fcntl.h:extern int posix_fallocate(int,off_t,off_t);
/usr/include/sys/fp_io.h:fp_ftruncate(  struct file     *fp,
/usr/include/sys/fp_io.h:extern int     fp_ftruncate();
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              ftruncate();
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              truncate();
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              ftruncate(int, off_t);
/usr/include/unistd.h:  extern int              truncate(const char *, off_t);
```

As to dd providing a "sparse" file, and not locking space. My understanding is that is the definition of a "sparse" file - logical space occupied, not physical space. Further, re: dd, if no "seek" argument is given, then the file should not be sparse - but will take time and effort by the IO subsystems.

Yes - much later with an answer - but that is because I am researching fallocate on AIX - and a possible bug I found in an application using fallocate() (the call!, actually posix_fallocate()) on AIX.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the calls of the truncate() family (ftruncate(), etc) not only to reduce, but also for expand files. Simply "truncate" them to a larger size as their current one. On filesystems supporting files with holes in them, it will be fast, much faster as appending the required null-blocks to the end of the files.

Comment: thank you. I see the man page for truncate() call on AIX but no executable ..so perhaps have to compile the C code.

Comment: @jays200 Yes, also I found this problem. Finally I implemented my own truncate tool, it was around 10 lines in C with error handling.

Comment: This creates a sparse file, which does not reserve space. @jays200 `truncate` is what your attempt with `dd` did, it won't help you.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry I didn't read the question very well. But I think it depends also on how the actual fs implements truncate.

Comment: Yeah I tried truncate() and truncate64() and it did create a sparse file.

Comment: wondering if fallocate also create sparse files? if not how does it pre-allocate disk space so quickly...

Comment: I tried fallocate on a Linux box and it's not a sparse file.